# Sequelize allowing non-unique column entries even with unique set to true?

Tags: database, sequelize.js

I have a sequelize model where 2 column entries need to be unique. The email entry works fine and sends an error if a non-unique email is given. However, the username field will be entered even if one already exists in the database. Is there more I need to add to the second unique validator to get it to work?

Here is my model:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  var User = sequelize.define("User", {

    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true,
      validate: {
        isEmail: true
      }
    },
    username: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
      unique: true
    },
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    profileImg: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      defaultValue: "default.png"
    }
  });

  User.associate = function(models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Post, {
      onDelete: "cascade"
    });
  };

  User.prototype.validPassword = function(password) {
    return bcrypt.compareSync(password, this.password);
  };

  User.hook("beforeCreate", function(user) {
    user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10), null);
  });
  return User;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mindset was still on MongoDB and I wasn't dropping the database after changes to my model. After dropping and recreating the database, everything works fine.